# how can I run code on Sitecore on an event under a specific security account?

Tags: events, context-user

The events handlers in Sitecore run under `default\anonymous` (i.e. `onpublish:end:remote`). Can I run the code under `Extranet\anonymous` account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your code in the below code snippet for the specific user. Here is the code.

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(@"extranet\Anonymous", true);
   
using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(user))
{
    // Add your logic 
}
```

Refer to this article for more code snippets.

https://www.nehemiahj.com/2012/03/how-to-use-securitydisabler-and_15.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks  for the prompt answer, worked like a charm!

Comment: @stelioskaltsounis If this solved your issue. Kindly mark it as accepted so it can be helpful for others. With my answer there is an up and down arrow. Below the down arrow there is a right sign to accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `UserSwitcher`. **UserSwitcher** allows a segment of code to run under a specific user instead of the current context user.

```
private void SecurityUserSwitcherExample(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itemToEdit, Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itemToDelete)
{
   //User which is already created in Sitecore User Manager
   string anonymousUser = @"extranet\Anonymous";
 
   //User existing or not
   if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(anonymousUser))
   {
 
      //Getting Sitecore User Object with UserName
      Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User scUser =
      Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(anonymousUser, false);
      //Switching Context User
      using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(scUser))
      {
         //Using EditContext to edit an Item
        using (new Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext(itemToEdit))
        {
           itemToEdit["Text"] = "Modified Text from Code";
        }
 
        //Using extranet\Anonymous to delete an Item
        itemToDelete.Delete();
      }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, all fine! I don't know how to mark it as answered.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, If this answer or any other one solved your issue or helps to resolve it, please mark it as accepted for the community. For more details https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers